# Small hinges for reusable domino rally

Tags: hinges

I am building a reusable domino rally.  Each domino will be attached to a large board with a small hinge.  Tilting the board to the side will then reset all the dominoes at once.

The hinges need to have low friction so that each domino can fall without resistance.  Since there will about 1000 dominoes, it would be nice if the hinges were cheap as well.  Does anyone know where to buy these hinges in bulk?

Comment: about 30 years ago I had a domino set designed just for this. They were specially weighted (top heavy) dominos that clipped into plastic tracks to 'hinge'. Maybe scour ebay to see if you can find them.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's going to be tough to find 1000 hinges of any usable quality for a price that you will like. Even if you find hinges for $0.25 each, that's still pretty expensive.

I would look at using a piece of fabric or webbing as the hinge. A couple dozen feet would be good for the whole project. If you glued the webbing tight to the board and tight to the domino in a sharp 90 deg angle, the width of the game piece should keep it from falling away from the webbing and will keep it in a upright position. It should be able to fall towards the webbing with no problem.

I would set up a small test of a dozen pieces though before committing to any method.

You might even want to cheat a little and bevel the bottom of the domino just a touch so that it leans away from the direction it needs to fall. This will help with resetting the game board.

Comment: Good ideas!  I actually tried you fabric suggestion, though, and the main problem was that it wasn't flexible enough over a such sharp corner.  (The fabric actually propped up the dominoes a little bit)  Maybe webbing would be better.

Comment: You could try a super light fabric like silk. It should still be cheaper than metal hinges.